# How to compute $E[B_t(\int_0^t f(s)dB_s)]=E[\int_0^tdB_s\int_0^t f(s)dB_s]=E[\int_0^t\int_0^t f(s)dB_sdB_s] $?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

For standard $1$-dimensional Brownian motion $B_t$, if for a function $f$ we have
$$
E\left[\int_0^t f(s)dB_s\right]=0
$$
what is the expectation of following and its distribution?
$$
B_t\left(\int_0^t f(s)dB_s\right)
$$

I try to rewrite it
$$
E\left[B_t\int_0^t f(s)dB_s\right]=E\left[\int_0^tdB_s\int_0^t f(s)dB_s\right]=E\left[\int_0^t\int_0^t f(s)dB_sdB_s\right]
$$
I am stuck here.

There is a useful formula:
$$
\int_0^t f(s)dB_s=f(t)B_t-\int_0^tB_sdf(s)
$$

Comment: You can show that $\int_0^tf(s)dBs \sim \mathcal N \left( 0, \int_0^tf^2(s)ds \right)$ is independant of $B_t$.

Comment: @blamethelag Do you use Ito isometry? Apply it we have $E[(\int_0^t fdB_t)^2]=E[\int_0^t f^2dt]$. Why the variance is $\int_0^s f^2ds$? Also, why $\int_0^s f(s)dB_s$ must be Gaussian?

Comment: The variance being what it is comes precisely from your use of the Ito isometry. The stochastic integral being Gaussian comes from the definition and approximation : if $f$ is a step function it’s trivial and otherwise approach is in $L^2$, the stochastic integral is a limit in $L^2$ of Gaussian variables and it is standard that the distribution limit of Gaussian variables is Gaussian with parameters being the limit of the parameters.

Comment: Ok, I see. But why $\int_0^t f(s)dB_s$ is independent of $B_t$? From definition of B_t, we know $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $B_{s}$.

Comment: @blamethelag We can assume $B_0=0$. I am still confused how to get $\int_0^t f(s) dB_s$ is independent of $B_t$?

Comment: I said something wrong, it is not independent of $B_t$ but it is independent of $B_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a consequence of the Itô isometry, the covariance of $B_t$ and $\int_0^t f(s) dB_s$ is given by:

$$\mathbb{E} \left( B_t \int_0^t f(s) dB_s \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t dB_s \int_0^t f(s) dB_s \right) = \int_0^t f(s) d\langle B, B \rangle_s = \int_0^t f(s) ds$$

Being the $L^2$ limit of Gaussian processes, $Y_t = \int_0^t f(s) dB_s$ is a Gaussian process itself, and by Itô's isometry, $Y_t \sim N\left(0, \int_0^t f(s)^2 ds \right)$. Thus, $(B_t, Y_t)$ is a jointly normal random variable, with mean zero and covariance given by:
$$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
s& \int_0^t f(s)ds \\
\int_0^t f(s)ds & \int_0^t f(s)^2ds
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It follows that $B_t Y_t$ follows a [product-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Correlated_central-normal_distributions) distribution.

Comment: But why $\int_0^t f(s) d\langle B, B \rangle_s = \int_0^t f(s) ds$? Ito isometry is $E(\int_0^t f(s) dB_s)^2=E \int_0^t f^2(s) ds$.

Comment: @Lucas Are you asking why is $d \langle B, B \rangle_s = ds$? That's because the quadratic variation of $B_t$ is just $t$.

Comment: @Lucas if you are asking why is $\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t X_s dB_s \int_0^t Y_s dB_s \right] = \int_0^t \mathbb{E}(X_sY_s) ds$, then apply Itô's isometry to the stochastic integrals of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ and use the fact that $XY = 1/4 [ (X+Y)^2 - (X-Y)^2 ]$

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense!